# Urlfetch with OAuth2 on same domain with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this situation :

- 2 accounts on the same domain
- Each account have the two sames Apps Scripts functions (basically: fetch and doGet)
- function doGet() is deployed as Web App, access only for domain
- **Problem: I can only fetch the function doGet() from the same user**

I did a plan to understand easier:

[image]

test_doGet:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"code": 200, "data": "aaaa"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return output;

}
//deployed as Web App, only domain to access
```

test_fetch:

```
function fetch() {

  let options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    }
  };
  //DEPLOYMENT_ID is changing if we fetch test_doGet() from USER 1 or USER 2
  var url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec";
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(r.getContentText()); //return error if test_doGet() from different user
}
```

Note: if i'm logged into user 1, and I enter manually the URL in the browser of test_doGet() from User 2, it's working fine!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you deployed the doGet() function did you select the option to execute the app as you or as the user accessing the app?

Comment: Both was tested without any difference

Comment: From your showing script, when the access token is used as the query parameter like `https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec?access_token=###` and the request header is removed, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Error 403 with the access token as query parameter. With the initial fetch, I found out that I have to share the doGet file project, at least as viewer, in order to make the fetch work from the different user. Is there no other solution to avoid to share the project?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed your reply. I apologize for this. About `I found out that I have to share the doGet file project, at least as viewer, in order to make the fetch work from the different user.`, this specification has been implemented on April 11, 2018. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#4-client-users-access-to-web-apps-using-curl-google-apps-script-and-so-on-which-dont-use-browser)

Comment: If you want to access the Web Apps using a script, it is required to share it with users. But, if the user directly accesses to the Web Apps URL instead of the fetch API, it is not required to share it. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this specification.