# Call an app script from another script with UrlFetchApp.fetch without manual log in

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-oauth, urlfetch

I have the same problem as described here: [Google Web Apps - Get user email but run scripts as owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905684)

The given solution is to create a client script that runs as the current user and a middleware script that runs as the owner. The client script then calls the middleware script with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(...)` and the middleware handles the request in the `doGet(e)` function. This  works fine in a test environment.

But to have it productive, I need to have the middleware script only accessible by domain users. Than, the `UrlFetchApp.fetch` call returns a login dialog.

So, is there a way to call a Google App Script by URL without manual log in?

This is my frontend script that runs with the user's privileges:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var data = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(backendCall());
  // TODO: Format data as HTML
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(data);
}

function backendCall() {
  const url = `${backendUrl}?user=${encodeURI(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())}`;

  const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: { 
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`,
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
}
```

And the backend script that runs with the owner's privileges:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(getUserData(e.parameter.user)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function getUserData(user) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues() // Get whole sheet data. This is much faster than getting data row by row.
      .filter((row) => row[cols.user] === user) // Select data for selected user.
      .map(formatRow)                           // Format sheet row to JavaScript objects.
      .sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day);           // Sort by date.
  return JSON.stringify(data);                  // Return as JSON string.
}
```

The result is, that the backend script returns not the data, but the error message "Error 401 Unauthorized".

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do step by step? If the users are running a script that uses `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` then the login request is unavoidable because this [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) uses a scope that requires authorization.

Comment: More details would be appreciated indeed. For what I understand so far, if your webapp is deployed only for domain, you can use Urlfetch adding ```ScriptApp.getAuthToken()``` in headers AND the project file must be shared with domain too (at least as viewer)

Comment: @WaximCorp What do you mean with "the project file" and "shared with domain"? Of course I deployed both projects.

Comment: The project file, which contains the code, must be shared (not the same as deployed), at least as viewer. Tell me if this is the same problem  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020770/urlfetch-with-oauth2-on-same-domain-with-apps-script

Comment: When I share the project, nothing changes. Question 75020770 seems to be related but the problem is not very specific there so I cannot tell if it's the same problem. But based on it I adopted my code and now I get a 401 instead of an login dialog.

Comment: Could you confirm that the user from frontend script has rights to see the backend project file?

Comment: I can confirm it. It's also not working when I run the frontend as the same user as the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your codes and made some modifications in order to make it work :

For both projects :

- Go to Setup, and check `display manifest "appsscript.json"` to ON
- Modify your appscript.json with `oauthScopes` like following :

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "DOMAIN"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
}
```

Your front-end project :

```
const backendUrl = "https://script.google.com/.../exec";

function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(backendCall());
  //instead of : HtmlService.createHtmlOutput
}

function backendCall() {
  const url = `${backendUrl}?user=${encodeURI(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())}`;

  const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: { 
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
      }
  };

  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
}
```

Back-end project:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(getUserData(e.parameter.user)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function getUserData(user) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById([ID_SPREADSHEET]).getSheetByName([SHEETNAME]); 
  //instead of  getActiveSheet()

  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues() 
               .filter((row) => row[cols.user] === user)
               .map(formatRow)                          
               .sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day);           

  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I think the "oauthScopes" was what was missing.