# How to tell a doPost function that can be accessed by "Anyone within MY-DOMAIN" that "The account is in the domain"

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, urlfetch

When I deploy a doPost (or doGet) function as a wep app,
I can choose the "Who has access" options:

- "Only myself"
- "Anyone within MY-DOMAIN"
- "Anyone with Google account"
- "Anyone"

When I choose "Anyone with MY-DOMAIN", how to tell the doPost function that the access user is within the domain?

I want to use "Anyone within MY-DOMAIN" instead of "Anyone" for security.

## What I tried to:

**1. I prepared a `doPost` function as follows in a stand-alone script.**

```
function doPost(e) {
  const json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const text = json.text;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(`The text you sent is "${text}"`);
}
```

**2. I deployed it and copy the URL of the web app.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YFJ7.png)

**3. I preared another stand-alone script to access the `doPost` function as follows.**

```
function myFunction() {

  const app_url = "-----------Copied URL in the process #2.-------------";
  
  const data = {'text': "Hogehoge" };

  const params = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()},
    "ContentType": "application/json",
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(app_url, params);

  //Expected to output 'The text you sent is "Hogehoge"' 
  console.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

I think the request header should contain some information about the account execute myFunction, but I'm not entirely sure `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()`is appropriate.
To get the identityToken, I added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" scope in appscript.json.

**4. I execute `myFunction()` using an account within the domain. The returned text was**:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about doPost, but for make it work with doGet, you need to do like this : `https://script.google.com/a/macros/<DOMAIN>/s/<DEPLOYMENT_ID>/exec?access_token=<TOKEN>` with the token provided by this function `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75020770/urlfetch-with-oauth2-on-same-domain-with-apps-script

Comment: As the additional information to Waxim Corp's comment, I think that in order to access Web Apps, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` is required to be included. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script And, please confirm that you can make users access your Web Apps to the administrator of Google Workspace.

Comment: @Waxim Corp Thank you very much for your help. I succeeded to do what I wanted to with your help and Mr.Tanaike's help.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your all help. I achieved my goal with `access_token` and required scope and sharing my script.

Comment: @miwa About `Thank you for your all help. I achieved my goal with access_token and required scope and sharing my script.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your help. I accepted your answer (^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In order to access Web Apps, please use the access token in your situation.

  - In your situation, this might be the reason for your error message.
- `"ContentType": "application/json",` should be `"contentType": "application/json",`.

  - But, from your showing `doPost`, this might not be required to be used.
- Please use the access token to the query parameter of `access_token` instead of the request header.
- Please share the Google Apps Script project of `doPost` with the users you want to access.
- In order to access Web Apps using the access token, please add the scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.
- Please confirm that you can make users access your Web Apps to the administrator of Google Workspace.

When these points are reflected in your script, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Scopes

About the scope, from `To get the identityToken, I added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" scope in appscript.json.`, please use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

#### 2. Share Google Apps Script project

Please share the Google Apps Script project of `doPost` with the users you want to access.

#### 3. Modified script

Please modify your showing script as follows.

```js
function myFunction() {

  const app_url = "-----------Copied URL in the process #2.-------------";

  const data = { 'text': "Hogehoge" };

  const params = {
    'method': 'post',
    "contentType": "application/json", // This might not be required to be used.
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }

  const query = `?access_token=${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`;
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(app_url + query, params);

  //Expected to output 'The text you sent is "Hogehoge"' 
  console.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about the actual setting of your Google Workspace. When this didn't resolve your issue, I would like to recommend confirming whether you can make users access your Web Apps to the administrator.
- When I saw [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75020770/7108653) showing in Waxim Corp's comment, I noticed that I didn't post it as an answer. So, in order to summarize this, I posted this as an answer.

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)